# Can't get computed field to work

Tags: 7, nodes, entities

This is the code:

```
$number->field_max['und'][0]['value'];

$array = array(
    "7mm Shorty over 7mm Jump" => 10,
    "7mm Shorty over 5mm Jump" => 14,
    "7mm Jump" => 13,
    "5mm Shorty over 5mm Jump" => 16,
    "5mm Shorty over 3mm Jump or 7mm Shorty over 3mm Jump" => 19,
    "5mm Jump" => 19,
    "3mm Shorty over 3mm Jump" => 20,
    "3mm Shorty over 2mm jump" => 24,
    "3mm Jump" => 24,
    "2mm Jump" => 27,
);

foreach ($array as $i) {
    $smallest[$i] = abs($i - $number);
}
asort($smallest);

$closest = key($smallest);

$suit = array_search($closest, $array);

$entity_field[0]['value'] = $suit;


$display_output = $entity_field_item['value'];
```

I want it to display the value closest to the number entered in the field_max field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In response to various comments and other answers, here is some code that ought to work:

```
$number = $entity->field_max['und'][0]['value'];

$array = array(
  "7mm Shorty over 7mm Jump" => 10,
  "7mm Shorty over 5mm Jump" => 14,
  "7mm Jump" => 13,
  "5mm Shorty over 5mm Jump" => 16,
  "5mm Shorty over 3mm Jump or 7mm Shorty over 3mm Jump" => 19,
  "5mm Jump" => 19,
  "3mm Shorty over 3mm Jump" => 20,
  "3mm Shorty over 2mm jump" => 24,
  "3mm Jump" => 24,
  "2mm Jump" => 27,
);
$smallest_value = PHP_INT_MAX;
$closest_value = -1;
foreach ($array as $val) {
  if(abs($val - $number) < $smallest_value) {
    $smallest_value = abs($val - $number);
    $closest_value = $val;
  }
}
$entity_field[0]['value'] = $closest_value;
```

After this code is done, `$closest_value` should be set to the value closest to the initial value.  You can output this however you like.  In the display value field, there should be something like `$display_output = $entity_field_item['value'];`

Comment: I put that code in, it's not showing any errors but it's not showing the field either. This explains the $entity_field_item part http://drupal.org/node/149225.

Comment: I updated my code to save the result to a field.  You'll want to put your `$display_ouput` code in the display field.  I am not positive about the first line, but that really depends on how your fields are being saved, what they are called, and so on.  I will say that it doesn't follow the pattern that usual computed fields conform to.

Comment: If you are using display suite module just chick if the field is not disable in manage display tab.

Comment: Thanks. I put it in and got a rather large error.. http://pastebin.com/SgXDZ6yu

Comment: It's not set to hidden and I can get it to show a simple line of text.

Comment: The error is caused because `$field_max` isn't defined.  I am STILL pretty unclear on where that variable is supposed to come from.  Is there an example you're working from?

Comment: you are right, you just need to use the value of your field correctly, i'm never used computed field but i will looking for the answer for you

Comment: I've updated my code to reflect how reading the value in ought to work.

Answer (score 0):

Just edit the first line, and change it to the following one.

```
$number = $entity->field_max['und'][0]['value'];
```